# sorting nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have dictionary like this:

```
input = {9: { 3: 0.0003 , 2: 0.0002}, 8: {1: 100.0, 2: 50.0, 3: 300.0}}
```

Output must be like this:

```
output = {8: {2: 50.0, 1: 100.0, 3: 300.0}, 9: {2: 0.0002, 3: 0.0003}}
```

Tried `OrderedDict` , `sorted` etc. but still not get my desired output.

Comment: 1. You only want to sort then outer level? 2. Are you aware that dictionaries have arbitrary order prior to CPython3.6? 3. WHY do you want to sort a dictionary? 4. Please show your attempt with `OrderedDict`.

Comment: @timgeb Yup, i was ready to tell him that too :-)

Comment: @timgeb i have tried this 

1. OrderedDict(sorted(input.items()))

2. {k: (dict(v.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))) for k,v in input.items()}

3. dict(sorted(input.items(), key=lambda (x,y): (x,sorted(y.items(), key=lambda (a,b): b))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply [`collectiobs.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) twice to get inner and outer sorted dictionaries:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

data = {9: { 3: 0.0003 , 2: 0.0002}, 8: {1: 100.0, 2: 50.0, 3: 300.0}}

result = OrderedDict(
    sorted(
        (k, OrderedDict(sorted(v.items(), key=itemgetter(1))))
        for k, v in data.items()
    )
)

print(result)
```

Which gives:

```
OrderedDict([(8, OrderedDict([(2, 50.0), (1, 100.0), (3, 300.0)])), (9, OrderedDict([(2, 0.0002), (3, 0.0003)]))])
```

**Note:** `OrderedDict` is only needed for < Python 3.6, since dictionary order is not maintained. Otherwise, you can rely on ordered insertion of keys and sort them normally, as seen in [@U9-Forwards's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53943591/sorting-nested-dictionary-in-python/53943632#53943632) answer.

Comment: Thanks bro it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use `OrderedDict` instead, as how @timgeb mentions dictionaries have arbitrary order prior to CPython3.6:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
OrderedDict([(8, {1: 100.0, 2: 50.0, 3: 300.0}), (9, {3: 0.0003, 2: 0.0002})])
```

Comment: your proposed solution doesn't match with my desired output as mentioned above in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use *dict comprehension* with `sorted` twice:

```
>>> input = {9: { 3: 0.0003 , 2: 0.0002}, 8: {1: 100.0, 2: 50.0, 3: 300.0}}
>>> {k:dict(sorted(v.items())) for k,v in sorted(input.items())}
{8: {1: 100.0, 2: 50.0, 3: 300.0}, 9: {2: 0.0002, 3: 0.0003}}
>>>
```

For python versions under 2.7, use:

```
>>> input = {9: { 3: 0.0003 , 2: 0.0002}, 8: {1: 100.0, 2: 50.0, 3: 300.0}}
>>> dict([(k,dict(sorted(v.items()))) for k,v in sorted(input.items())])
{8: {1: 100.0, 2: 50.0, 3: 300.0}, 9: {2: 0.0002, 3: 0.0003}}
>>>
```

Comment: This is not available for all python versions. Just as a note.

Comment: @Netwave Thanks for the note, i'll edit.

Comment: i think it is under python3.6

Comment: @Netwave No. python2.7

Comment: I think Netwave wasn't talking about the dict comprehension syntax ;)

Comment: @timgeb Then what is it?

Comment: @Netwave I have to go, so can you please edit for me?

Comment: @timgeb Same with you.

Comment: The ordering you will get prior to CPython 3.6 with your code is random.

Comment: @timgeb Oh, yeah, that's right.

Comment: @U9-Forward i tried both solutions but didn't find my desired output.